# Change Liquibase's logging level in the plugin

Tags: maven, logging, liquibase

I know this has been asked, and I've found many answers, none of them are working for me.

I've got a Maven POM with the Liquibase plugin (liquibase-maven-plugin) v 3.6.3 that generates thousands of lines of DEBUG level messages, for example:

```
13:03:29.399 [main] DEBUG liquibase.servicelocator.ServiceLocator - ServiceLocator.findClasses for liquibase.database.Database
13:03:29.399 [main] DEBUG liquibase.servicelocator.ServiceLocator - ServiceLocator finding classes matching interface liquibase.database.Database
```

I've tried the following as found in other questions/answers:

```
<properties>
    <liquibase.logging>info</liquibase.logging>
</properties>
```

and

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    ...
    <configuration>
       <logging>info</logging>
       ...
```

and the above using the following property:

```
       <logging>${liquibase.logging}</logging>
```

and this option on the mvn command line:

```
-Dliquibase.logging=info
```

Despite all combinations of the above, including nothing, which should cause it to default to "INFO", I still get "DEBUG" level messages. Is this a known bug or is there some other setting that I've overlooked?

Thanks

Comment: Mat be that adding "log4j.logger.LiquibaseSchemaResolver=INFO" helps. Try looking at  https://github.com/mattbertolini/liquibase-slf4j/issues/8

Comment: There is currently a pull request to fix a bug - that bug may have existed in 3.6.3 as well. See https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/pull/918

Comment: @gile - I looked at that issue, it makes sense, however, I'm at a loss as how to provide that logging information to the liquibase maven plugin.

Comment: @SteveDonie - I'll look for that update, if I get a chance, I will also look to see what they set the default logging level to.